# Symfony2: locale, date and French format

Tags: symfony, internationalization, twig

There is something I do not understand with locale management in Symfony2. I want to write month name in French with *date* Twig method. Is it possible? I can't do it.

It seems that my locale is not taken into account.

Here is my *app/config/config.yml* file:

```
framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallback: fr }
    secret:          %secret%
    charset:         UTF-8
    router:          { resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml" }
    form:            true
    csrf_protection: true
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:      { engines: ['twig'] } #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    session:
        default_locale: fr
        auto_start:     true
```

Session locale seems good:

```
echo $this->get('session')->getLocale();  // Returns "fr"
die;
```

Yet, when I am using, in my view, the following:

```
<td class="month">{{ history.date|date('F Y') }}</td>
```

It returns me "July 2011" for instance, instead of "Juillet 2011".

What am I misunderstanding? Shouldn't the *date* filter be localized? If not, how can I do to retrieve correct terms? I used to use I18N to translate all the month names, but I do not think it is the best practice.

Comment: I used [Brian Clozel](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10736988/229088) solution with success.

Comment: I suggest that solution too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) does not return localized string. You have to use [strftime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) for that. Alternatively you can use [SonataIntlBundle](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataIntlBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/reference/datetime.rst) if you want more control.

Comment: OK. Thanks. So I will keep my current method with a translation file for month names.

Comment: Adding a bundle just for this seems way overhead. Unless you already use that bundle.