# Symfony2: How can I set twig |date("d F, Y") filter to output months in Swedish?

Tags: php, date, datetime, symfony, twig

I'm having problems with the |date("d F, Y") filter in my twig templates.

I want the months to be outputted in Swedish. I have tried setting "locale: sv" in my parameters.yml files but I get no effect.

It was working before I upgraded to from Symfony 2.1 to 2.3 so I think that might have something to do with it.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**The Twig Intl Extension**

You can use the [Twig Intl Extension](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig-extensions/blob/master/lib/Twig/Extensions/Extension/Intl.php) found in *fabpot*'s official Twig extension [repository](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig-extensions).

It provides a localized date filter which can be used like this:

```
{{ date | localizeddate('full', 'none', app.request.locale ) }}
```

use `app.request.locale` as third parameter for current locale or just `'sv'`.

**Integration into your project**

add the official extensions to your `composer.json` using:

```
composer require twig/extensions:1.0.*@dev
composer update twig/extensions
```

**config.yml**

```
#enable intl extensions
services:
    twig.extension.intl:
        class: Twig_Extensions_Extension_Intl
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

---

**quick tip:**

another handy extension is the Text extension providing *truncate*,...etc filters

```
services:
    twig.extension.text:
        class: Twig_Extensions_Extension_Text
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying this out now, since all the dates on this site should be printed in the same language, what would be the best way to not repeat {{ date | localizeddate('full', 'none', *myLocaleValueFromParameters.yml* ) }} on every single place?

Would writing a twig macro or twig extension be the best way to go?

I find it strange that there are no implementation against the parameters.locale key already built in

Comment: you can use the localized date filter and pass your `parameters.default_locale` to twig as a global using `twig.globals.global_locale: %default_locale%` , then use something like `{{ date | localizeddate('full', 'none', global_locale ) }}`

Comment: Thanks! I'll go with that and make a twig macro of it that takes the date object and formats it with the localizeddate filter to prevent repetition in the templates. :)

Comment: I have successfully installed some other Twig extensions, but when I install the `new Twig_Extensions_Extension_Intl()` I get the following error: `The intl extension is needed to use intl-based filters.`. What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Is not a configuration problem but a parametrization problem. Wrong ICU format.

Comment: You could need to set up the extension in your xampp or wamp php.ini 

@see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27967876/intl-working-fine-with-symfony2-on-wamp-but-show-an-error-in-functional-tests

Comment: Is there absolutely no documentation available for this extension ? :(

Answer (score 3):

I will make an addition to solution posted by @nifr.

In order to use your date format install the Twig Intl Extension and than you can use:

```
{{ date|localizeddate('none', 'none', app.request.locale, null, 'dd MMMM, yyyy') }}
```

The last argument in my example is a date format - here is a documentation: http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime

Here is the Twig Intl Extension documentation: https://twig-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intl.html

Answer (score 3):

The [twigphp/Twig-extensions](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig-extensions) package is now archived:

> WARNING: This repository is abandoned in favor of Twig Core Extra extensions.

You can install [twig/intl-extra](https://github.com/twigphp/intl-extra) instead to use [format_date()](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/format_date.html) using [ICU syntax](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/#datetime-format-syntax):

```
{{ date|format_date(locale='sv', pattern='EEEE d MMMM yyyy') }}
# Söndag 26 mars 2023
```

**Note**: requires the PHP **intl** extension.

Answer (score 2):

`|date` filter use `DateTime::format` function which doesnt support locales. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744952/php-how-to-format-a-given-datetime-object-considering-localegetdefault) and write your own twig extension.

Comment: own twig extension is not needed :) see my answer.

Comment: if you like to include whole bundles for small function $)

Comment: @nifr own twig extension is needed. the provided answer requires one to change all `|date` filters in twig files, sounds like a workaround, not a robust solution.

Comment: @AlexeyB. Thanks for your answer but the provided link has nothing to do with Twig Extensions. I think you may reconsider this situation.