# Intl working fine with Symfony2 on WAMP, but shows an error in Functional Tests

Tags: php, symfony, intl

I have a quite strange issue here!

I am using **Symfony2** with WAMP. When I visualise a path, lets say

```
mylocaldomain/blog/see_all
```

it works fine (Intl extension on PHP works fine).

However, when I build a functional test, there is this issue

> 500 Internal Server Error - Twig_Error_Runtime:
>   An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("The Symfony\Component\Intl\DateFormatter\IntlDateFormatter::__construct() method's argument $locale value NULL behavior is not implemented. Only the locale "en" is supported. Please install the "intl" extension for full localization capabilities.") in ...

I think 2 version of `php.ini` were used. If this is the problem, how to know which one is used for tests?

If this is not the problem, any clues?

Comment: run `php --ini` from the command line. you might have to use full path to php if you don't have it on your `PATH` env variable.

Comment: Thank you Himal, I tried to add the path to php.ini to the path. I still do not work. What do you mean by using the full php path? Where? in the test command?

Comment: No, you don't have to add php.ini path to the `PATH` varaible.i meant the php executable so you can just type `php --ini` from the command line.it'll show you the ini file used by the tests/command line tools.

Comment: It works! thanks a lot Himal! If you want to answer, i'll mark it as resolved!

Comment: Glad to hear that. no worries, you can post what you did as an answer and mark it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Himal (see comments above), here is the solution:

The `php.ini` used by the WAMP and by the console are not the same (`php --ini` for the one in the console).

I enabled in both of them the **Intl extension**

```
extension=php_intl.dll
```

Another solution is to make the console, use the same file as WAMP (I did not explore this solution, but it seems to me to be "cleaner").