# Twig: Translate DateFormat-> Day

Tags: symfony, twig, translation

I have this in my twig-template

```
{{ returnDate|date("l, d.m.Y") }}
```

The ouput is `Friday, 08.05.2015`.
Its it possible to translate the dayname -> `"l"`?
Something like this `{{ returnDate|date("l, d.m.Y")|trans }}`

Comment: have a look at this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364206/symfony2-how-can-i-set-twig-dated-f-y-filter-to-output-months-in-swedish
they speak about a localizeddate filter. Maybe it can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem minutes ago! I pushed a simple, quick & dirty solution:

```
{{ returnDate | date("l") | trans }}, {{ returnDate | date("d.m.Y") }}
```

Comment: THANKS!! This works for me! Maybe not the best solution but it works great!