# Twig: show the name of the months based on the current locale

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm just trying to show the name of the months based on the current locale.

```
{{ event.date|date('F') }}
```

but the months are always shown in english...

I have tried this code below I found [here](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/issues/378), but the result is the same...

```
class Helper_Twig extends Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            'datetime' => new Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'datetime')
        );
    }

    public function datetime($d, $format = "%B %e")
    {
        if ($d instanceof \DateTime) {
            $d = $d->getTimestamp();
        }

        return strftime($format, $d);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'Helper';
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** In the controller I'm checking the current locale using `$request->getLocale` and it corresponds to the locale parameter I'm switching in parameters.yml.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [SonataIntlBundle](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataIntlBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/reference/datetime.rst) to handle localized date representation. `Intl` library needs to be installed though.

Comment: I'd recommend using Twig's Intl extension instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23424315/1001110

Comment: It doesn't provide a method to display only the translated month.

Answer (score 4):

Since you defined `datetime` TwigFilter, you don't have to call `{{ event.date|date('F') }}`

Instead, you should call this `{{ event.date|datetime('%B') }}`

Answer (score 2):

You probably haven't installed the PHP `intl`-library in your PHP. http://php.net/manual/de/book.intl.php

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed the `IntlExtension` you can use `format_datetime` with custom pattern.

```
{{ event.date|format_datetime(pattern="MMMM") }}
```

docs:

- https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/format_datetime.html
- https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/#datetime-format-syntax