# Symfony 2 setlocale (LC_ALL, 'de_DE')

Tags: php, symfony, twig, setlocale

I would like to display a date in TWIG in German.

```
{{ event.beginnAt |date('l d.m.Y')}}
```

But the output is "Friday 28.06.2013".

Where should I use the setlocale function that displays the date in German?

Comment: did you check your parameters.yml ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to render a DateTime object in a Twig template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318914/how-to-render-a-datetime-object-in-a-twig-template)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable [twig intl extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/dic_tags.html#twig-extension) (it requires enabled [intl functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) in php) a then you just use:

```
{{ event.beginAt | localizeddate('full', 'none', locale) }}
```

---

**Edited**:
If you want to just localized name of day, you can create your own Twig extension:

`src/Acme/Bundle/DemoBundle/Twig/DateExtension.php`

```
namespace Acme\Bundle\DemoBundle\Twig;

class DateExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{

    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('intl_day', array($this, 'intlDay')),
        );
    }

    public function intlDay($date, $locale = "de_DE")
    {

        $fmt = new \IntlDateFormatter( $locale, \IntlDateFormatter::FULL, \IntlDateFormatter::FULL, 'Europe/Berlin', \IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN, 'EEEE');
        return $fmt->format($date);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'date_extension';
    }
}
```

Then register it in services.yml

`src/Acme/Bundle/DemoBundle/Resources/config/services.yml`

```
parameters:
    acme_demo.date_extension.class: Acme\Bundle\DemoBundle\Twig\DateExtension

services:
    acme_demo.twig.date_extension:
        class: %acme_demo.date_extension.class%
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

In your Twig template you can use just:

```
{{ event.beginAt|intl_day }} {{ event.beginAt|date('d.m.Y') }}
```

Comment: Thank u very mutch! But now i have an other problem.
event.beginnAt | localizeddate('full', 'none', 'de')

gives out Freitag, 28. Juni 2013.

But i only want Freitag, 28.06.2013

Comment: The filter "intl_day" does not exist in templatefile.

Comment: Okay. I dont register the yml in PageExtension. Now it work. But i get an other Error: "Method "beginAt" for object "Event\PageBundle\Entity\Event"

Comment: It's typo – I've written `beginAt`, but you use `beginnAt`

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve that I used the [SonataIntlBundle](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/intl/master/doc/reference/datetime.html) it exposes some twig function that are formatted with intl.

Example:

```
 {{ date_time_object | format_datetime(null, 'fr', 'Europe/Paris',
constant('IntlDateFormatter::LONG'), constant('IntlDateFormatter::SHORT')) }}
```

will output

```
 '1 février 2011 19:55'
```

I used a simpler approach since I forced the local of the php execution context and, after that, just replaced the date function by format_datetime. Remember to see the supported patterns as they differ from the strftime. You have a link on the SonataIntlBundle for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setlocale()` and `strftime()`, using something Symfony-specific might be overhead.