# symfony 2 number and date format

Tags: symfony, internationalization, symfony-2.3

I am developing a multi country multi language application and one of the issues I have are the decimal point separator and the date format. I am aware of the setLocale method, but the only changes I have seen are in translations. Do I have to use PHP's built in setlocale method to format the number and date correctly or is there another way?

Also, numbers (money) are stored in database MySQL, should I use a datatransformer at the form fields with using the locale or will they be handled automatically by symfony?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Numbers and Money in forms**

For numbers and money in form fields symfony has already a [number](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/number.html) and a [money](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/money.html) form type which handles the decimal point and grouping depending on the locale.

**Number and Date formatting on output**

Normally you format a date (in twig) with the date filter like `mydate|date("m/d/Y")` But you can set it for the complete twig environment, so you only have to call `mydate|date`. But this is only recommended, if the locale requirements are static for the complete application and not dynamically based on the users locale. For this you should consider a twig extension which @jkucharovic and @Kris have posted.

Comment: This is bad solution. For each request will be wasted system resources by doing unnecessary job – new listener injecting Twig and overwriting  default formates – even if it wouldn't be used.

Much better solution (and also less demanding) is create custom Twig extension and call it only if it is needed.

Comment: yep, removed the listener and added a hint to you post.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Twig International extension](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig-extensions/blob/master/lib/Twig/Extensions/Extension/Intl.php)

For number format there is [number_format](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/number_format.html) however you may have to build your own extension to use NumberFormatter

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to create custom Twig Extension with [PHP intl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php). You can take a look into [my answer to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17360634).

```
namespace Acme\Bundle\DemoBundle\Twig;

class IntlExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{

    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('intl_day', array($this, 'intlDay')),
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('intl_number', array($this, 'intlNumber')),
        );
    }

    // Other methods…

    /**
     * NULL locale cause load locale from php.ini
     */
    public function intlNumber($number, $locale = NULL)
    {
        $fmt = new \NumberFormatter($locale, \NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
        return $fmt->format($number);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'intl_extension';
    }
}
```

Then in your Twig template you can use:

```
{{ entity.number_value|intl_number(app.request.locale) }}
```

or if you use Symfony < 2.1 `app.session.locale`