# can I customize a html|raw in twig

Tags: html, security, symfony, twig, validation

I am looking to secure some wysiwyg input in a symfony2 application, I have been looking at some flat php plugins like htmlpurifier but just tweaking the twig standard functionality like variable|raw_secure with some own parameters would suffice, if there is a way to create a filter that inherits from the |raw but lets me specify a few tags that are allowed...

Anyone done that?

I need to protect myself from xss, javascripts etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> “if there is a way to create a filter that inherits from the |raw but lets me specify a few tags that are allowed...”

Twig's filter `raw` [does nothing](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/blob/master/lib/Twig/Extension/Escaper.php#L99-L107) with parameter passed to it.

You can use Twig's filter [`escape`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/escape.html) with specific strategy. If that solution doesn't fit – you can create your [own Twig filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17360634).