# Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Tags: php

here is my array i get

```
 Array
(
[0] => BugHerd_Project Object
(
    [id:BugHerd_Project:private] => 24323
    [name:BugHerd_Project:private] => bugherd a
    [devurl:BugHerd_Project:private] => http://st.com/a/
    [active:BugHerd_Project:private] => 1
    [created:BugHerd_Project:private] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2014-05-03 11:15:22
            [timezone_type] => 2
            [timezone] => Z
        )

    [updated:BugHerd_Project:private] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2014-05-05 06:55:52
            [timezone_type] => 2
            [timezone] => Z
        )

)
```

)

/**
   * Gets date the project was last created
   * @return DateTime Project creation date
   */

```
public function getCreated() {
return $this->created;
 }
```

- i have written below code for to access date from array

  on doing print_r($projects_particular->getCreated());

  output of array is here :

  ```
    DateTime Object
   (
   [date] => 2014-05-05 10:04:30
  [timezone_type] => 2
  [timezone] => Z
    )
  ```

  i recived error:Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

  - im just want to access date.

Comment: is this the `DateTime` object? to return a string, you should use `format()`

Comment: 1) That's not an array, it's an object of class `DateTime` (it says so in the printout). 2) "Want to access date" is unclear. Would you be OK with printing the date as the number of microseconds elapsed since my birthday? If not, why not?

Comment: This question has been asked multiple times:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134174/symfony2-catchable-fatal-error-object-of-class-datetime-could-not-be-converted

Comment: check my updated array that i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function getCreated() {
return $yourarray->created->date;
 }

public function getid(){
   return $yourarray->id
}
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined property: BugHerd_Project::$date here is the error recived

Comment: check now $yourarray->created->date;

Comment: thanks rayan it worked you understand my question correctly thanks you rayna babu

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object could plaese resolve this simple issue

Comment: here is the function public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
  }

Comment: your array is not valid on this function . non object means your $this variable does't have any values on this function . try to print before you process.