# twig filter from date to string

Tags: string, datetime, filter, twig

Using Symfony 2.3.4 and Twig.
I'm trying to show an objects attribute which is, and I quote, "an Object of Class DateTime" and I need something to convert it to a string(I'm guessing a filter).

```
{{ r.birthday }}
```

Any tips appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to render a DateTime object in a Twig template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318914/how-to-render-a-datetime-object-in-a-twig-template)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use the `date` filter if you want to display the date in a static format (for instance, if you allways want to display something like 2014-05-07, regardless of the locale of the user), or you can use the `localizeddate` filter to display a date that is localized for the user's language and location.

For instance, if you always need the same format:

```
{{ r.birthday|date('Y-m-d\\TH:i:sP') }}
```

will always return a date/time in the following format:

> 2014-05-07T08:39:11Z

which is useful for machine-readable date strings, for instance in an Atom feed.

However, if you want to display date/times for humans, I'd recommend using the `localizeddate` filter:

```
{{ r.birthday|localizeddate('long', 'short') }}
```

will return something like:

```
February 6, 2014 at 10:52 AM (using English locale)
6 februari 2014 10:52 (using Dutch locale)
6 février 2014 10:52 (using French locale)
6. Februar 2014 10:52 (using German locale)
```

See [my answer on 'How to render a DateTime object in a Twig template'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23424315/1001110) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html

```
{{ r.birthday|date("m/d/Y") }}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `r.brithdaty` is instance of DateTime object you can easily use the `format` command to return the string format:

```
{{ r.birthday.format('m/d/Y') }}
```

Follow this link for more info [DateTime Format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)