# How do I format time to hh:mm using Twig (Symfony)

Tags: html, symfony, twig

I retrieve a timefield from my MS SQL database, for example '10:30:00' (hh:mm:ss). I try to render this in a twig template, but I only want to display the '10:30' portion (hh:mm).

I've tried to get this done using both number_format and date_format, but I can't seem to get it done. For example, a failed attempt would be:

```
<td class="PODTIME">{{ record.PODTIME|number_format(2, ':') }}</td>
```

Yeah that doesn't make sense. But I can't find anything even remotely close to what I want - I guess I'm overlooking something.

Thanks

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use the Twig filter date like this :

```
{{ object.date|date('H:i:s') }}
```

As seen on this thread : [How to render a DateTime object in a Twig template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318914/how-to-render-a-datetime-object-in-a-twig-template)

Comment: Please note it works only for time going from 00:00:00 to 23:59:00. If time is a period longer than 24 hours, it will not works.

Comment: `h` instead of `H` for 12 hours

Comment: if time is null then it will show the current time, do this trick
 `{{ object.myTime ? object.myTime|date('H:i:s') }}`

Comment: When I do this on a unix date (or a number of seconds really, just want to format them as hour:minute) I get an additional hour on everything. Anything to do with my LOCALE? so a value of 300 should be formatted as 00:05 but instead becomes 01:05. Consistently over all my entities...