# Twig - format date

Tags: php, datetime, twig

I am working on a project built with [craft cms](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/datetime), that uses twig templating, and I would like to format the date in to this kind of format:

```
13. June 2017
```

I am not sure how to do that, I have tried with php date functions:

```
{{ entry.dateUpdated.date('j. F Y') }}
```

and also with:

```
{{ entry.dateUpdated.localeDate('j. F Y') }}
```

But, none of them worked. How can I do that?

Comment: as you can see I already did

Comment: Is it works as you required??

Comment: No, that is why I posted the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to render a DateTime object in a Twig template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318914/how-to-render-a-datetime-object-in-a-twig-template)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try this

```
{{ entry.dateUpdated  | date('j. F Y') }}
```