# Month number instead of month name in Symfony DateType field

Tags: symfony, twig

I use Symfony 4.3 and 'bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig' as form theme. How can I setup DateType field to show month numbers instead of month names?

```
{{ form_widget(formConge.DateBureauOrdre.month, {'var': {'choices': {'label': {'jan': 'a' }} } }) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a `DateType` form field, you have an option there called `format` which can be used to format the day & month & year fields.

More information can be found on [Symfony Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#format)

You would better pay attention to **deprecation notice**:

> Deprecated since version 4.3: Using the format option when the html5 option is enabled is deprecated since Symfony 4.3.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Twig date format for this purposes, something like the following:

```
{{ object.date|date('d/m/Y H:i:s') }}
```

Also, check out this thread: [How to render a DateTime object in a Twig template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318914/how-to-render-a-datetime-object-in-a-twig-template)